# KendoUI Recursive Template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-listview

I cam trying to construct a `ListView` using `KendoUI`.

Because of this, I need to create a `ClientTemplate`.

But what I want to know is, after creating the `ClientTemplate`, how can I use that template inside itself.

In other words I want to create a `Recursive Template` if that makes sense.

This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="submenu-item">
         #:Name#
    </div>
    <div class="submenu-children">
         # foreach (var child in ChildElements ) { #
             // In here I want to reuse this same template.
         #}#
    </div>
</script>
```

The idea behind this is so that I can create a `ListView` of elements and all its children. I would format the children to be tabbed in slightly.

Any help will me much appreciated.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle/dojo with your current approach?

Comment: It is a but hard because I am using a KendoUI Library. Not quite sure how to link that in.But here is a link which shows an implementation of this but non recursive. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/listview/index I just created a Model which has a list of that model to mimic a child. So what you would want to do is recursively display each child until you are at the `leaf of the tree`. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do a #foreach inside your template, just make a call to

```
#= kendo.render(kendo.template($("\\#template").html()), data.ChildElements) #
```

You may run into an error if the bottom-most child elements don't have a ChildElements property, in that case just add a

```
# if(data.ChildElements !== undefined && data.ChildElements.length > 0 ) { #
    #= kendo.render(kendo.template($("\\#template").html()), data.ChildElements) #
# } #
```

See somewhat working sample at http://jsbin.com/fagawo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you for this. Made a slight improvement to this and it works great. http://jsbin.com/xavuwinobe/2/edit